# List Count does not go to nextRow C++

Tags: visual-c++

The past few days, I've been desperately trying to fix an issue with my list count in C++.
    This is my function that handles Count & Add new `plr` in list.

```
/*Iterator for players*/

list<Player*>::iterator itc;
list<Player*>PlayerCount;

int FindPosition(list<Player*>List, Player* plr)
{
    int pos = 1;
        for (itc = List.begin(); itc != List.end(); itc++, pos++)
        {
            if ((*itc) = plr)
                break;
        }
    return pos;
}

What i'm trying to do is implement each time someone Queue in my list.
My output is currently showing this :
Player One Queue. Player Two Queue
it keep saying : Player in queue [1]
like there was no implementation for next row

How it Should be.
Player One : Player in queue [1]
Player Two : Player in Queue [2]
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: `if ((*itc) = plr)` is assigning `plr` to `*itc`, where you trying to do a comparison : `if((*itc) == plr)`?

Comment: Wow, I was blind and now i see clear ! it just work like a charm =)

Comment: Glad I could help. The same thing has bitten me some many times =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the problem was the `if ((*itc) = plr)` was assigning `plr to *itc` instead of performing a comparison `if ((*itc) == plr)`.

One friendly suggestion,

> In `FindPosition` function, `list<Player*>List` is being passed by value which means that you are creating a copy of the whole list every time that you are calling the function. If that is the intended behavior then you can keep it as is otherwise you could rewrite it as follows:

```
// pass List by value
// int FindPosition(list<Player*>List, Player* plr)
// pass List by reference
int FindPosition(list<Player*>& List, Player* plr)
{
    int pos = 1;
        for (itc = List.begin(); itc != List.end(); itc++, pos++)
        {
            // changed from assigment (*itc) = plr 
            // to comparison (*itc) == plr
            if ((*itc) == plr)
                break;
        }
    return pos;
}
```